# What does SPI mean in the context of WebKit?

Tags: webkit

The abbreviation "SPI" comes up a lot of in the [WebKit codebase](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/WTF/wtf/spi), as well as [WebKit maintainer discussions](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=180686).

The term seems to have the following meanings associated to it:

- Low(er)-level API in use by WebKit logic
- Underlying implementation to be supplied by the platforms that WebKit compiles to.

So this has quite a bit of similarity with the term PAL ([Platform Abstraction Layer](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143358)), in particular it feels like it means "an API belonging to PAL".

However, googling "SPI" only gives [Serial Peripheral Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface), which is probably not what the abbreviation is referring to here. Does it just mean something like "system programming interface"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SPI** stands for **service provider interface** and it's essentially a plugin-based architecture, where a platform can define some abstract functionalities as interfaces. The various plugins can then define implementations for these interfaces to provide this functionality.

The name for this pattern was widely used in Java, but it's now being used in other languages/frameworks as well.

This [post](https://mariospr.org/2013/02/03/accessibility-in-webkitgtk/) contains a more detailed description of a Webkit SPI for accessibility.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface